# Can't use video file

Tags: html, css, utf-8, youtube, adobe-brackets

I'm trying to import a video onto my site. I don't want any controls, I just want it to play. I'm using the  tag, but when I downloaded the video from YouTube and tried to use it, it said that "Brackets only currently supports UTF-8 encoded files". (Brackets is my code editor) I opened the file in Notepad++ and converted it to UTF-8 to no avail. I downloaded an extension to convert it to UTF-8, also not working. Here's the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMd580H8rGY

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to upload the video on your server then add to your page something like:

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

More info : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

READ THE DOC !

Comment: The muted attribute doesn't work, I want it to automatically start playing, and there's a bunch of ugly controls.

Comment: you have to read the doc as minimal if you want exactly what you want ....

Answer (score -1):

YouTube give option named by Embed in side share button

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LMd580H8rGY?ecver=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

this is HTML Code

change the height & width from iframe